# spring-boot gradle plugin can't be found

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I have a separate gradle script that is just adding spring-boot plugin. It looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-release' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.8.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
```

Then, in another project, it is referenced like this:

```
apply from: '../../food-orders-online-main/spring-boot.gradle'
```

When I run build task I'm getting the following error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'spring-boot']
> Plugin with id 'spring-boot' not found.
```

Someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I got **`The plugin id 'spring-boot' is deprecated. Please use 'org.springframework.boot' instead.`**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Applying a plugin by plugin id is not supported in script plugins. You must use the plugin's fully qualified class name.

```
apply plugin: org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin
```

See [this thread](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-include-buildscript-block-from-external-gradle-script/7016) for more information.

**UPDATE:** Updating plugin class name.

Comment: Does anything has changed in 1.4.0 version of Spring Boot? Is the plugin class name still the same?

Comment: This also solved my problem for `Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle * or later. The current version is Gradle *` error

Answer (score 18):

Whoever comes here in 2024+, do yourself a favor, go to the spring starter (spring boot template generating tool) [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/) and generate a template project from there, and build step-by-step from there. Change/add one variable at a time and check it.

## Original Answer

These are the Plugins that I am using on spring boot 2.0.1

> ```
> apply plugin: 'java'
> apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
> apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
> ```

My complete vanilla gradle file here (Spring boot 2.0.5)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: This also works with Gradle 4 and Spring Cloud Finchley SR1.  As of August 2018, the Spring Cloud Finchley SR1 "quickstart" instructions seem to be for an older version of Gradle, because as documented on the Spring Cloud web site, it does not work with Gradle 4.  Spring Cloud is on top of Spring Boot 2.  I only got it working using this answer.  (Note, not shown in this answer, but you do also need the `buildscript` section shown in another answer.)

Answer (score 8):

This code works for me

```
 plugins{

  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.3.RELEASE'

 }
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Add:

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           maven {
               url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
           }
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.4.RELEASE"
       }}
   ```
2. Change:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
   ```

   to:

   ```
   apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from SpringBoot 1.4.0.RELEASE the plugin package has been slightly changed.

```
apply plugin: org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax  and where your parentheses close  `}`  I had the same issue and it turned out my repositories {  didnt contain `}` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar exception

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find spring-boot-gradle-plugin-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:20220216.230329-214)
```

Running the gradle build with --refresh-dependencies fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me:-

```
buildscript {
ext { springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'}
repositories { mavenCentral() }
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot- 
starter-web', version: '2.0.5.RELEASE'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**After proxy setting** ( What is the proxy IP in your organization), I have added following code in **build.gradle** file. The problem has gone.

```
sourceSets {
main {
    output.setResourcesDir(java.outputDir)
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As of now July first 2020, this is how I was able to configure it, and it worked! Hopefully, this can help anyone facing this problem.
Note: Pay attention to the versions

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.2.8.RELEASE')
        }
    }
    
    plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.8.RELEASE'
        id 'java'
    }
    
    group 'org.capfer'
    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    
    dependencies {
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.2.8.RELEASE')
    }
```

Answer (score -6):

could it be, that you don't have a @SpringBootApplication with a main(String[] main) on your classpath ??