# plugin with id 'org.springframework.boot' not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I would like to include the spring boot plugin to my project using gradle 5.2.  Below is the current state of my build.gradle, followed by things I have tried to do.  Currently, I am trying to use gradle 5's [BOM support](https://gradle.org/whats-new/gradle-5/#fine-grained-transitive-dependency-management), but this is not a hard requirement.  I just want to know how to solve the error

> plugin with id 'org.springframework/boot' not found

**UPDATE:** Updated the structure below to better represent my use case.

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: 'boot.gradle'
```

**boot.gradle**

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

dependencies {
    implementation platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.0.RELEASE')

    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'

    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
}
```

To recreate my error, you need only one more file in your project:

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have attempted to implement the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26580254/4249424), which is based on

> In external scripts (we call them script plugins), plugin IDs cannot
>   be used. Instead, the fully qualified class name has to be used. This
>   is a known bug.

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50182142/4249424) which isn't working for me, even if I upgrade to use spring 2.0.5.

As well as various other similar solutions.

Comment: Is `org.springframework/boot` a typo or does the error really have a slash? Any sort of network proxy that might be blocking the download or artifacts from maven?

Comment: @Mike fixed the typo, thank you.  I use maven for many artifacts on other projects, so that should not be a problem.

Comment: is it basic spring boot app? or trying convert existing app to spring-boot? @buratino

Comment: @Deadpool It has been a spring-boot app from the start.

Comment: then after some changes it broken? actually the problem is not clear for me @buratino

Comment: @Deadpool what kind of changes do you mean?  If you import my build.gradle and application.java, are you able to build the project without seeing the same error as me?  What can I do to make the problem more clear?

Comment: the real problem here , is that you did not define the `buildscript {}` block on top of your build.gradle script, to declare the `classpath` dependency to `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` :  see documentation here https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot  (you should use the first approach with `plugins` DSL ). The second problem is that you should not define yourself Spring modules version, but rather use `io.spring.dependency-management` to make use of Spring BOM : this is well described here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution for my use case is based on Abdelghani's answer.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply from: 'boot.gradle'
```

**boot.gradle**

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

dependencies {
    implementation platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.0.RELEASE')

    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'

    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
}
```

In short, the buildscript needed to have 'org.springframework.boot' available as a plugin for `apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'` to work elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

You can try with spring BOM dependencies management as below :

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```