# Spring boot 2.3.3.RELEASE project fails build with exception "org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException" in gradle version 5.6.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

my gradle version is 5.6.3.

while I run a spring boot project of 2.3.3.RELEASE with 'gradle clean build' it shows me following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.3.3.RELEASE')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

**Updating my question:**

my build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group = 'net.project'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and my settings.gradle contains just the root project name

Comment: Spring Boot requires 6.3 as of version 2.3. Although it should support 5.6 but with the old syntax and not the new one. Next to that you are probably better of using the gradle wrapper (./gradlew on the command line) instead of your own local gradle installation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [plugin with id 'org.springframework.boot' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55145066/plugin-with-id-org-springframework-boot-not-found)

Comment: @M.Deinum Spring Boot 2.3 does not require 6.3. It supports 5.6 and 6 (6.3 and later). Also, AFAIK, you can use Gradle's new plugin syntax with Gradle 5 or 6.

Comment: 2.3.3.RELEASE of the plugin is [in the Portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot/2.3.3.RELEASE) so I think this should have worked. Perhaps a temporary network problem prevented the plugin from being resolved. If the error's occurring repeatedly and you don't believe there's any  network problem, can you update your question with a build.gradle (and settings.gradle if you have one) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @rimirezaduity That works fine for me so I suspect a problem with your connection to the plugin portal. Can you build with `--debug` and update the question with the relevant parts of the output? It should show the HTTP requests that Gradle is making and what the responses were.

Comment: so turned out the envirnment I was working in, it got all the outgoing urls blocked and also I was not aware of the fact.... hence the issue happened. In that sense it was a network issue. Initially I also thought it might be a version issue. So thanks to everyone for responding, Thanks @AndyWilkinson .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring boot 2.3.3.RELEASE definitely exists on gradle central plugin repository as I can see [here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot/2.3.3.RELEASE). You're most probably building behind a corporate firewall with outgoing URL disabled. Had the same issue earlier, which I solved it by asking the IT Operations team(*nicely*) to allow `https://plugins.gradle.org/` requests to go through. For security reasons if they don't allow this then you can ask them to create a local mirror server as instructed [here](https://plugins.gradle.org/docs/mirroring)